# How to remove the cache in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching, resources

I need you to clear the cache always. But when I create, update or delete a client, always get the same result.
Only when I delete the cache manually (Ctrl+Shift+Supr) I can see the new data.

```
.factory('Clients', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource(pathApi, {}, {
        query: {
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: false
        }
    });
}])
```

---

```
angular.module('app.controllers').controller('controller', ['$scope','Clients', function ($scope,  Clients) {

            Clients.get().$promise.then(
                //success
                function (value) {
                    $rootScope.clients= value;
                },
                //error. 
                function (error) {
                   alert(error);
                }
            );
  }]);
```

Comment: Isn't there a `cache` property that you can pass in as config.

Comment: Something like this? 

.factory('Clients', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource(pathApi, {}, {
        query: {
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: false, 
            cache: false
        }
    });
}])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20804750/resource-query-is-not-displaying-the-latest-data-after-a-server-side-data-mod) is the solution. Add a time variable to the request: params: { 'foobar': new Date().getTime() }

```
.factory('Clients', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource(pathApi, {}, {
        query: {
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: false,
            params: { 'foobar': new Date().getTime() }
        }
    });
}])
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work for me:

```
app.run(function($rootScope,$templateCache) {
  $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
    $templateCache.removeAll();
  });
});
```